# Java image editor UI component

Tags: java, image, user-interface, editor

I'm looking for a Java library that provides a simple image editor (like MS Paint) as a UI control.  If it's extendable so I can add new editing tools, that would be great.  I need to be able to save the edited image in either JPEG or BMP formats.  This library must be free, and ideally is open source with a license compatible with including in closed source software.

My use case is I'm using Xuggle/MediaTool to extract frames from a video file.  I then need to have the user cut out certain pieces of the image to create a mask for use in a video processing routine.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to [roll one on your on](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html). If you need really advanced capabilities, probably you can embed the editor from [this open source Java project](http://aoi.sourceforge.net/screenshots).

Answer (score 1):

I made a "photoshop/mspaint" like Java project here : http://imagework.free.fr contact me through the "contact" page of the website, I can help you if you need.

To answer, for write an JPG/BMP image you can use:

BufferedImage image = "your image";

```
ImageIO.write(image,"BMP",BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED);
```

or

```
ImageIO.write(image,"JPG",BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
```